# Advanced verilog design analysis

Tags: optimization, verilog, fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I'm trying to implement a design into a Virtex II Pro FPGA (from Xilinx). The problem is the design is overmapped, taking up too many resources. To overcome that, I needed to know which blocks of my code are the most demanding (require more resources - LUTs, FFs, Slices, etc). By that I mean: How many resources is this if-else ( or switch-case, while, etc) requiring?

Xilinx doesn't have a tool for this purpose. Is there a workaround? Or, even better, is there a 3rd party tool capable of doing this?

Since my FPGA is quite old, I'm using ISE and PlanAhead 10.1.

Comment: Take a look at the various reports ISE generates. Somewhere you should find information about what resources were used by which part of your Verilog code.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use ISE 10.1 recently after a long hiatus. I don't remember what would be the better solution, but this worked for me:

- In the synthesis option, set the option "Netlist Hierarchy" to "Rebuilt".
- Start the process "Implement Design" -> "Translate" -> "Floorplan design"

You should see be able to navigate your hierarchy and see the resources usage of the sub-modules.

Answer (score 1):

If we have one module to synthesize, I think there is no way to see which hardware is related to a specific `if` or `case` statement, because synthesis tools synthesize all the code **together**.(for example sometimes 2 or 3 processes in your vhdl code is synthesized to a specific hardware). Actually according to the **synthesis options** and **constrains** it guess that what hardware could be generated.

However if you want to see the resources usage of each module (not each `if` statement) you can see the **Synthesis Report** on "ISE -> project -> Design summary". If you synthesized your code without any errors **Synthesis Report** tell you how many resources (LUT, FF, IO, Buffer,  ..) is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Xilinx tool **PlanAhead** which is not really intended for this, but gives a nice, hierarchical breakdown with information on resource usage for any block on any hierarchy level. I can only provide an obfuscated screenshot at the moment, but it should give you an idea of what to expect.

[image: PlanAhead screenshot]

PlanAhead can be opened from within Xilinx through Tools > PlanAhead > "Floorplan Area/...".